# Datatables with YADCF - 'Copy URL' button with with applied filters

Tags: datatables, url-rewriting, copy, yadcf

I use the Datatables script with YADCF filters. I need to create a new "Copy URL" button that copies the page URL with the applied filters. I added a script that uses the "**URLSearchParams**" and allows to get the filtered column data. For example, if I type ***example.com/table?category=DAA*** URL manually in the browser address bar, it filters the data in the "Category" column and shows the relevant result.
However, I am not sure how to improve this script and:

1. make the URL be updated dynamically in the address bar when you change filters OR save the updated URL on the server (what approach will be easier);
2. get this URL with applied filters from the server;
3. make the "Copy URL" button to copy this URL to the clipboard.
   The copied URL should have a similar format: ***example.com/table?category=DAA&function=Data%20Con&bits=12*** (where *example.com/table* is the link to the page on the site)

I uploaded the whole code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/GuT04wDkcGDzV7y5?preview
The part below allows to use the parameters in filters:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const whichCategory = urlParams.get('category');
    if ( whichCategory !== null ) {
  yadcf.exFilterColumn( productTableVar, [[0, whichCategory]]);
}
const whichFunction = urlParams.get('function');
if ( whichFunction !== null ) {
  yadcf.exFilterColumn( productTableVar, [[1, whichFunction]]);

}

const whichBit = urlParams.get('bits');
    if ( whichBit !== null ) {
  yadcf.exFilterColumn( productTableVar, [[3, whichBit]]);
}
```

An important note: the columns include content in HTML format with special characters (& or /) and spaces.

I will appreciate your help. Thank you.